# MYSQL get count from inner SELECT and use same ORDER BY

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to program a simple chatbot but I have a problem with my SQL query

```
SELECT `msg_id`,`msg` FROM `chatbot_msg`
WHERE `msg_id` in (
    SELECT `msg_id` FROM `chatbot_msgtags`
    WHERE `tag_id` in (
        SELECT `tag_id` FROM  `chatbot_tags`
        WHERE :question LIKE CONCAT('%',tag,'%') 
        )
    GROUP BY `msg_id`
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= :relevance
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
);
```

I tried different ways to get the tag count. for example with the AS statemant or by adding it to the frist and second select part but both gives errors

if I only use

```
SELECT `msg_id`, COUNT(*) as count FROM `chatbot_msgtags`
WHERE `tag_id` in (
    SELECT `tag_id` FROM  `chatbot_tags`
    WHERE :question LIKE CONCAT('%',tag,'%') 
    )
GROUP BY `msg_id`
HAVING COUNT(*) >= :relevance
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

I have no problems at all but I want to get everything with 1 query for better speed

also ordering is only working with the second statement

EDIT:

My Solution is

```
SELECT m.`msg_id`,`msg`,`count` FROM `chatbot_msg` as m,(
    SELECT `msg_id`, COUNT(*) as count FROM `chatbot_msgtags`
    WHERE `tag_id` in (
        SELECT `tag_id` FROM  `chatbot_tags`
        WHERE :question LIKE CONCAT('%',tag,'%') 
        )
    GROUP BY `msg_id`
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= :relevance
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
) AS t2
```

thanks to xpy
I had to add the table name for msg_id in the first select

EDIT2:

I found a better solution with joins

```
SELECT `msg_id`,`msg`, COUNT(*) as count FROM `chatbot_msgtags`
LEFT JOIN `chatbot_msg` USING( `msg_id` )
WHERE `tag_id` in (
    SELECT `tag_id` FROM  `chatbot_tags`
    WHERE :question LIKE CONCAT('%',tag,'%') 
    )
GROUP BY `msg_id`
HAVING COUNT(*) >= :relevance
ORDER BY count DESC
```

because I'm not sure if the first version is working correctly

Comment: good hint, easiest solution

Comment: Well, it's a step in the right direction

Comment: added solution with join to question

Comment: When the word 'in' no longer appears in the solution, then we'll be close

Comment: sorry have no clue how to query for more than one element without the in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT `msg_id`,`msg`,`count` FROM `chatbot_msg`,(
SELECT `msg_id`, COUNT(*) as count FROM `chatbot_msgtags`
WHERE `tag_id` in (
    SELECT `tag_id` FROM  `chatbot_tags`
    WHERE :question LIKE CONCAT(\'%\',tag,\'%\') 
    )
GROUP BY `msg_id`
HAVING COUNT(*) >= :relevance
)) a  ORDER count DESC;
```

Comment: worked nearly out of the box, added my version to question, thx

Answer (score 1):

There's a few other things a little odd in your query, but something like this should be just about right...

```
SELECT m.msg_id
     , m.msg
     , COUNT(*) count 
  FROM chatbot_msgtags mt
  LEFT 
  JOIN chatbot_msg m
    ON m.msg_id = mt.msg_id 
  JOIN chatbot_tags t
    ON t.tag_id = mt.tag_id
   AND :question LIKE CONCAT(\'%\',mt.tag,\'%\') 
 GROUP 
    BY m.msg_id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= :relevance
 ORDER  
    BY count DESC;
```

Comment: thx for the hint, totally forgot the group by is helping me out for multiple results on join. What else is a little bit odd? I want to improve the query further